# How do I plot a legend next to my title (outside plot) using R?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, legend, par

I'm using base R `plot()`, and I want a legend (a color block and key) to show up above (outside) the top right of my plot next to my title (generated using `title()`).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(4,1,3,2)
z <- c(1,2,3,4)
dat <- data.frame(x,y,z)

windows(width = 5, height = 9)        #quartz() on Mac
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE), heights=c(0.5,1))
par(oma = c(4,3,0,0) + 0.1, mar = c(0,0,1,1) + 0.1)
plot(dat$x, y=rep(1,4), type = "n", axes = F, ylab = "", xlab = "")
legend(x = "bottomright", legend = c("y", "z"), fill = c("blue", "red"))
plot(dat$x, dat$y, type = "n", main = "PLOT")
lines(z, col = "red")
lines(y, col = "blue")
```

Basically this makes two plots, one is just invisible and shortened so all that's displayed is the legend.
You may be able to addtionally tweak the margins around the legend and other graphical parameters (`?par`) to get the layout better.
[image]